# webrtc useEffect clean up function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, webrtc

I want to clean up webRTC in useEffect. I'm using await/async.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async() =>{
      try{
         pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
         if(callUserFlag){
            localVideoRef.current.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
            localVideoRef.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => {
               pc.addTrack(track,localVideoRef.current.srcObject)
            }) 
            const offer = await pc.createOffer();
            await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);

            socket.emit("call user", {
               offer: offer,
               toSocket: socketId
            })
         }
      }
      catch(err){
        console.error("Error: " + err);
      }
   }
   fetchData()
   return () => {
      cleanupFunction()
   }
},[])
```

Here is console result:
**Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createOffer')**

Comment: Seams like you pc is null. So you cannot read property of null (reading createOffer).
Try to console.log pc just before "const offer = await pc.createOffer();" to be sure it is not null and if not, if it has the property / method createOffer

Comment: I added condition `if(pc!=null){...}` and problem solved. Thx @JeanJacquesGourdin